# Confusion related with NIntegrate and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have the following problem:

Suppose that you have a differential equation

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, n[2] == 2}, n, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
```

And some initial condition

```
initial = n[2] /. sol1
```

Define another differential equation with initial condition in terms of the first one

```
sol2[l0_] := NDSolve[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, n[0] == initial}, n, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15]
```

I try to integrate, "sol2" but this doesn't work

```
NIntegrate[n[x] /. sol2[2], {x, 0, 10}]
```

**Solution**

I know the solution of the problem: Just put the numerical value of "initial = n[2] /. sol1", in this case "initial=2"

```
sol2[l0_] := NDSolve[{D[n[x]/(1 + x)^4, x] == 0, n[0] == 2}, n, {x, 0, 1000}, AccuracyGoal -> 15]
```

Then, the integral gives a numerical value

```
Im=NIntegrate[n[x] /. sol2[2], {x, 0, 10}]
```

However I was interesed if there is some way to "fix" the first method.

Comment: `initial` is a list of 1 element. You need: `initial = First[n[2] /. sol1]` for the `NIntegrate` to work.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution to my question.